# Player[] Changed from Array To Collection

Tags: java, java-7, bukkit

I get this error in the IDE. The error shows up under `Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()`:

```
Required: org.bukkit.entity.Player[]
Found: java.util.Collection               <capture<? extends org.bukkit.entity.Player>>
```

Here is the code.

```
public List<Player> getTargetV3(Arena arena, Player player, int maxRange, double aiming, boolean wallHack) {



    ArrayList target = new ArrayList();
    Location playerEyes = player.getEyeLocation();
    Vector direction = playerEyes.getDirection().normalize();
    ArrayList targets = new ArrayList();
    Player[] lx;
    int testLoc = (lx = Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()).length;

    for(int loc = 0; loc < testLoc; ++loc) {
        Player block = lx[loc];
        if(block != player && block.getLocation().distanceSquared(playerEyes) < (double)(maxRange * maxRange)) {
            targets.add(block);
        }
    }}
```

Comment: Wellcome to SO. I posted an answer, but next time, please append full stack trace of the exception thrown.

Comment: @James There is no stack trace. The error message is an IDE warning.

Comment: Ah, OK. There would be probably an exception if you launched this code.

Answer (score 2):

The error says that you used wrong data type (a `Collection` instance). You should convert your collection of players into array.

You can do it like this:

```
Player[] players = playersCollection.toArray(new Player[playersCollection.size()]);
```

Note: I used random variables names. Adjust the names to your variables.

Answer (score 0):

Spigot implementations overrides the Bukkit implementation:

https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/Bukkit.html#getOnlinePlayers()

Therefore, `getOnlinePlayers()` returns `Collection<? extends Player>` instead of `Player[]`. You should switch out to calls to a collection, not an array:

```
Collection<? extends Player> lx = Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers();
int testLoc = lx.size();

for (int loc = 0; loc < testLoc; ++loc) {
    Player block = lx.get(loc);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Even using a variable, I cannot force the compiler to use the collection version of the method. I'm building against Spigot 1.8-R0.1 using Eclipse.